# How to save apache2 file

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I am new to linux and the command line. I am using `VirtualBox` with `linux/ubuntu` and needed to open my `httpd.conf` file to add the following:

```
ServerName localhost
```

Now I am stuck here and cannot figure out how to save this and go back to the command line. I know this is easy for the pros but I am completely new at this.

Thanks!

P.S. I searched Google and stackoverflow as I was sure this would have already been answered but I could not find anything on it.

Here is the screen shot.

http://i451.photobucket.com/albums/qq235/tech0925/asdfsafsf_zps80a61cd1.png

Comment: Ok! It looks like you're using nano. Hit 'Ctrl + X', then 'Y', then 'Enter'

Comment: Worked great! Thank You! Yah I opened that way b/c it said the gedit function did not exist? Weird Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! If you're using Ubuntu, you can probably install gedit with `sudo apt-get install gedit` (I say probably because I'm more of a Fedora user)

Comment: @ChrisForrence: to use gedit you have to install a X-Server only for editing files! This is what i call "overkill" ;)

Comment: @deagh - Haha, true! I probably should have looked at the screenshot a bit more to make sure that he wasn't already in a desktop environment.

Comment: "searched ... stackoverflow ... but I could not find anything on it"—that would be because the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Try other Stack Exchange sites such as [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)—there's a large list of sites at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open your file for example with *vi*

```
vi /path/to/your/httpd.conf
```

after the file is open you can change to edit/insert modus of vi

```
:i
```

and edit your file. After editing you cann write and close your file

```
:wq
```

**//edit:**

you can store your file with *nano* (your editor)

```
CTRL+x
yes
```

Comment: Hmm, I'll admit to having never used `:i`. I just hit `i` (putting you into insert mode), then `ESC` when finished, then `:wq` to save and quit

Comment: Thank You. Yah I am completely new to the command line.